# Why boto3.client.download_file is appending a string at the end of file name?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I need to download files from s3, and I create this code:

```
#This function make the download of the files in a bucket 
def download_dir(s3:boto3.client, bucket:str, directory:str=None) -> None:
    
    #Verify if exist the bucket diretory
    if not os.path.exists(bucket):
                #Creating the bucket directory
                os.makedirs(bucket)
    
    # Iterating in s3 list of objects inside of the bucket
    for s3_key in s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)['Contents']:
        
        file_name=os.path.join(bucket, s3_key['Key'])
        #If the object is not a directory
        if not s3_key['Key'].endswith("/"):
            #Verify if the download file was already done  
            if not os.path.exists(file_name):
                print(s3_key['Key'])
                real_file_name = s3_key['Key']
                print(real_file_name)
                try:
                    s3.download_file(Bucket=bucket,Key=s3_key['Key'], Filename=file_name)
                except:
                    print(type(real_file_name))
                    s3.download_file(Bucket=bucket, Filename=file_name, Key=real_file_name)
        #If the object is a directory
        else:
            #If the directory doesn't exist
            if not os.path.exists(file_name):
                #Creating the directory
                os.makedirs(file_name)
    

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                verify=False,
                aws_access_key_id=aws_dict['aws_access_key_id'], 
                aws_secret_access_key=aws_dict['aws_secret_access_key'], 
                aws_session_token=aws_dict['aws_session_token'],
                region_name=aws_dict['region_name'],
                config=config
                )

download_dir(s3, 'MY-BUCKET')
```

But a in specific file, magicly is appending another string at the end of the bucket file name, which brings me an exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "aws_transfer.py", line 58, in                                                                                                                                                                                                    download_dir(s3, 'bucket')                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "aws_transfer.py", line 29, in download_dir                                                                                                                                                                                               s3.download_file(Bucket=bucket, Filename=file_name, Key=real_file_name)                                                                                                                                                                    File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 171, in download_file                                                                                                                                         return transfer.download_file(                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 315, in download_file                                                                                                                                       future.result()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result                                                                                                                                             return self._coordinator.result()                                                                                                                                                                                                          File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result                                                                                                                                             raise self._exception                                                                                                                                                                                                                      File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 126, in **call**                                                                                                                                             return self._execute_main(kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                          File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 150, in _execute_main                                                                                                                                        return_value = self._main(**kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 571, in _main                                                                                                                                             fileobj.seek(offset)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 367, in seek                                                                                                                                                 self._open_if_needed()                                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 350, in _open_if_needed                                                                                                                                      self._fileobj = self._open_function(self._filename, self._mode)                                                                                                                                                                            File "/home/gbarbo3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 261, in open                                                                                                                                                 return open(filename, mode)                                                                                                                                                                                                              FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bucket/folder/model.tar.gz.c40fF924'

The real file name must to be 'bucket/folder/model.tar.gz'.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you include the full log for the run that failed? Not just the error message, but also your print statements.

Comment: The appended string (`model.tar.gz.c40fF924`) is used to create a temporary file during the file transfer. Which line generated the error? Did you write this code, or is it from a website?

Comment: boto3 will append a random string to the end of the file during download.  The error is being caused because it's unable to create the file at all, likely because you're not creating a directory for it.  Unless you explicitly create objects in S3 that end in a "/", list_objects will not show them, so your "makedirs" call is never happening.

Answer (score 7):

Your program is having problems with sub-directories.

First, an explanation...

Amazon S3 does not use directories. For example, you could run this command to upload a file:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://bucketname/folder1/foo.txt
```

The object would be created in the Amazon S3 bucket with a `Key` of `folder1/foo.txt`. If you view the bucket in the S3 management console, the `folder1` directory would 'appear', but it doesn't actually exist. If you were to delete that object, the `folder1` directory would 'disappear' because it never actually existed.

However, there is also a button in the S3 management console called **Create folder**. It will create a **zero-length object with the name of the 'folder'** (eg `folder1/`). This will 'force' the (pretend) directory to appear, but it still doesn't actually exist.

Your code is specifically checking whether such an object exists in this line:

```
if not s3_key['Key'].endswith("/"):
```

The assumption is that there will always be an object with the name of the directory. However, that is not necessarily true (as shown with my example above). Therefore, **the program never creates the directory and it then fails when attempting to download an object to a directory that does not exist on your computer**.

Your program would need to test the existence of the target directory on your local computer before downloading *each* object. It cannot rely on there always being an object with a Key that ends with a `/` for every directory in the bucket.